# Retrieving subset of Array/List on Neo4j node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am fairly new to Neo4j and have the following problem at hand. I am trying to develop a social networking site wherein I would like to store the message exchanged between two users on their relationship property. For this, I am trying to store all their messages in the form of array/list on a relationship property.

Now i want to retreive only 4 messages per query from this array.
For ex. If the message list is like this :

["Hi", "Hey", "Name", "Nick", "Age", "23"]

Then, i want to be able to get a subset of this array depending on the index I call.
For example: How can i retreive elements from index 1 to 4 in a query.

["Hey", "Name", "Nick", "Age"]

Do arrays on property support such types of operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the neo4j version ( 2.0.0 -M6), use '..' as comma doesn't work.

```
Match a:User-[r:FRIEND]->b:user
Where a.name = 'a' and b.name = 'b'
Return r.message[1..5]
```

Answer (score 2):

In the version of 2.0.0-M05, you can return the range of a collection. Suppose you have a user 'a' and a user 'b', they are connected by the relationship [:FRIEND] with a property "messages" of ["Hi", "Hey", "Name", "Nick", "Age", "23"], and you want the message with index of 1 to 4,

```
Match a:User-[r:FRIEND]->b:user
Where a.name = 'a' and b.name = 'b'
Return r.message[1,5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lisa. Is there any similar sort of feature that exists in version 2.0.0-M03 ?

Comment: No, this is a new feature.